# JMeter JMS Publisher/Subscriber with Websphere MQ experiencing javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: jms, jmeter, publisher, subscriber

I have setup Jmeter to Publish to a Webshere MQ but through the Results tree listener it is giving me a Response Message :  javax.naming.NamingException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jndi/toolkit/chars/CharacterDecoder

Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

I think I followed setup steps correctly from this page :http://leakfromjavaheap.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/jmeter-and-websphere-mq-series.html?_sm_au_=iVV5P5vR626sDt7V

Thanks in advance!

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!!!

Thanks to one of the posters here :https://community.oracle.com/thread/1158121

basically you need to download File System Service Provide from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-419418.html

then copy providerutil.jar to jmeter lib folder.